# Как задать радиус скругления углам прямоугольника на PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

У меня есть прямоугольник, но углы у него острые, и я хочу добавить некий "радиус" чтоб углы стали глаже. Как это сделать?
`pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, self.rect)` - сам прямоугольник

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам может помочь параметр **border_radius**.

Пример:

```
rect = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 200, 100)
radius = 40
pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, rect, border_radius=radius)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло!

Comment: Рад помочь. Если мой ответ решил Вашу задачу, можете поставить галочку и закрыть тем самым вопрос. 
Удачной разработки!